# Video replace failed in MS Stream Classic, now even upload fails

Tags: streaming, upload, microsoft-teams

I wanted to replace 3 of my videos (university teaching materials) to a newer version of them on the classic version of MS Stream. The upload for all 3 of them succeeded and their processing started. So far, so good.

However, when I later checked on them, they got into some kind of errored state:

- These videos cannot be viewed anymore (neither the old or the new version). Actually they got into an unpublished state and student cannot even list the video. When they visit the direct URL for it, they get an error message.
- These videos have an error icon in my videos list, like this:
  [image: MS stream video list]
- I cannot replace them again. The upload immediately fails after 1-2 sec. (Reuploading the old version also fails.)
  [image: Upload error]

There is no error code at all, so it is hard to figure out what is going on.

Meanwhile I managed to upload my videos as new videos and they are fine that way. Therefore it is not an issue with the video files or format, but something failed during the replace process (for all 3 videos) and now:

1. The old version is not viewable.
2. The new version is not viewable.
3. I cannot make a new upload for them to replace them.

I would like to replace those videos, so the previous URLs would still work. Does anyone faced a similar issue before and managed to resolve it?

(I already tried to get help from MS support. They told me to uninstall and reinstall it. This is MS Stream, a web app in their cloud, so let's say the official support was not really helpful.)

Comment: I'd talk to the IT guys maintaining the server.

Comment: @Peregrino69 I already tried to get help from MS support. They told me to uninstall and reinstall it. This is MS Stream, a web app in their cloud, so let's say the official support was not really helpful.

Comment: @Peregrino69 Yes, this is just a university level Microsoft 365 subscription, but it is hosted in the MS cloud, not on university hardware. I contacted one of the university system administrators, who has administrative privileges. With his admin rights he can basically edit all videos uploaded at our university from a work account. But he just got the very same results as me.

Comment: Now of course the uni sysadmin can contact MS Support and maybe he will receive not a BS answer as I did. Or not. But if someone faced the same issue before me and managed to solve it somehow, that would be a delightful information for me :)

Comment: Well, it looks like there is some timeout after all, I just did not wait long enough. Approximately after 48 hours the old versions were seemingly rollbacked and now I can try to replace those videos again! Hopefully it will work now :D

Comment: LOL :D Best of luck!